# Dialogflow - Can the user send multiple responses for one intent, without triggering another one?

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

The agent requests three parameters from the user being email, address, and country.

The user **may** set the three parameters in one response, or in multiple ones.

Is it possible to set the parameters in three or more different responses without triggering another intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mark all three parameters as required, Dialogflow will automatically prompt the user for each of them, even if they don't provide them initially. See the [Parameters](https://dialogflow.com/docs/actions-and-parameters#required) documentation page for more details.

You can also customize the prompts that your agent will use to ask for any missing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

use slot filling, and in your required prompts, you can reprompt the message, all in one intent.

see

https://dialogflow.com/docs/how-tos/slot-filling

https://dialogflow.com/docs/concepts/slot-filling

https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/slot-filling